# Python transformar um numero em inteiro

Tags: python, for, int, range

```
import math
x=9
raiz=math.sqrt(x)
print raiz
for i in range (raiz,9): #Problema aqui
 i=i**2
 print i
```

Preciso criar um for com a raiz de uma operacao(sempre inteiro. 2, 3,4,5...)
mas quando tento usar o for da forma que fiz da erro. Diz que a raiz tem de ser inteiro(o python entende como 2.0 , 3.0 , etc.) Alguem sabe como posso tratar isdso?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa converter o `raiz` para inteiro

```
import math
x=9
raiz=math.sqrt(x)
print(raiz)
for i in range (int(raiz),9): #Problema aqui
    i=i**2
    print(i)
```